# Not able to install Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, google-api-dotnet-client

Until now I only used Visual Studio for Business Intelligence development and now I have to do something in C# that uses Google Drive API which has to be installed through NuGet Package Manager. Unfortunately I don't see this particular package in Visual Studio Extensions and Update manager. I though it may be related to lack of `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console` option in my VS, so I wanted to install package manager. I downloaded .vsix file, but when I try to install, it fails with message `This extension is not installable on any current installed products`. I got VS 2015, 2013 and 2010 installed.

So if I'm not able to install package manager, there is at least any way to install google drive api without involving NuGet?

Drive api package name: `Google.Apis.Drive.v3`

EDIT: I did reset all Visual Studio settings since it was set for Business Intelligence development, but this didn't help as well.

Comment: Have you tried downloading it directly https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2015?

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, I tried and this installation fails.

Comment: you could compile the client library yourself https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client although I recommend that you figure out why you cant install nuget compiling the library is not for the feign of heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your Visual Studio 2015 has installed the [latest update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs). The latest version for Visual Studio 2015 should be version 14.0.25431.01.

If your Visual Studio 2015 is the latest version, please try repair your Visual Studio 2015 to check whether there has any installation issue.

And you also can install nuget packages without NuGet Package Manager. Please download the NuGet package and unzip it to local folder, which will list all content of this package. Then add the dlls in the unzipped folder into your project through Add Reference.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that SSDT and BIDS are for use with project types that are specific to `SQL Server business intelligence`. Business Intelligence Development Studio is the primary environment that you will use to develop business solutions that include `Analysis Services`, `Integration Services`, and `Reporting Services projects`.

To my knowledge you are not going to be able to install NuGet on it or use it to develop an actually C# application.

I am going to take a wild guess here and say you are trying to use google drive with a Script task.   You can do this I did it a number of years ago.   The set up is a bit weird.  Your going to have to create a normal C# application in NORMAL visual studio with Nuget and it will install all of the Dlls for you at that time.

Now that you have all of the dlls.  You are going to have to dump them in GAC and the folders that SSIS needs

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents

The 100 part changes depending upon which version of Sql server you are using

- 2005 = 90
- 2008 = 100
- 2014 = 110 (I think I cant remember)

Once the dlls are in the correct folders you should then be able to use it in a scripting task.

Note:  I am not 100% sure any of this will even work anymore.  When I did it the client library still supported .net 3.5.  Now you need to be able to use .Net 4.5 I am not sure if the newer version of Sql server will be able to handle the higher level of .net dll or if they all require 3.5.

Checked with a coworker his guess is that Sql server 12+ should support .Net 4.5 dlls.

Comment: The problem is, that I'am using normal Visual Studio, not SSDT. Anyway, most reasonable thing is to download dependencies on other machine and copy them so SSIS could use them. I'll do it after work and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: If you are using normal visual studio you should be able to install NuGet.